What are the range and limit of sounds recordable by regular smart phones?
I tried to record the noise of an old air conditioner, using two smart phones (Motorola G Pure, and Honor 11). But I couldn't hear the noise in the recordings. The noise of the air conditioner sounds like a dryer or washer, and is its frequency outside the recordable range of regular smart phones? Thanks.

Smartphone mircophones are optimized for voice, thus the recorded frequencies may indeed be a limiting factor. But I would assume that other hardware filters that are dedicated to filter out environmental sounds are a bigger problem. Usually for that purpose multiple microphones exists in a smartphone. You could try to cover other microphones (holes in the shell) except the main mic to mute those microphones.

You should also mention which recording app/software you use. That could also have a big impact.
